# Limit access to a class function to child classes that inherit from the class

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a use case where there are some attributes that are common to different categories that I capture through a base class and then there are some category specific parameters that are assigned in the child class definitions. For example,

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.category_param = None

    def run_category(self):
        self.category_param.run()

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, cat_param):
        super(Child, self).__init__()
        self.category_param = cat_param
```

Although the function `run_category` has the same form for all instantiations of class `Child`, it does use a category specific param that is `None`/undefined in class `Parent`.

I am looking for a clean way to prevent being able to call `run_category()` from an instantiation of class Parent.

```
parent = Parent()
parent.run()    # Should throw an error
```

I would like the above code to throw an error message that I have control over (since the error message `None` has no attribute `run()` is undesirable and would be the current way the above code crashes).

A possibility is of course to define `run_category` as,

```
def run_category(self):
    if self.category_param is not None:
        self.category_param.run()
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("method run() is not available for abstract base class Parent")
```

but I was looking for something cleaner/more pythonic.

Comment: Why is `Parent` even instantiable if it's not a complete type? Have you considered making `Parent` an abstract base class?

Comment: I didn't know about abstract base classes. Will look it up